# If $f$ has a zero and $|f''|\leq M$, then $f$ is monotone on $(-h,h)$, where $h=\sqrt{2|f(0)|/3M}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> Let $f$ be twice differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and let $M$ be a bound
>   of $f''$, $|f''|\leq M$ on $\mathbb R$. Assume $f(0)\neq0$ and define
>   $h=\sqrt{\frac{2|f(0)|}{3M}}$. Prove that if $f$ has a zero in $(-h,h)$, it's
>   monotone in $(-h,h)$.

So let's assume there's a zero $a\in (-h,h)$ such that $f(a)=0$ and also there's $b\in (-h,h)$ such that $f'(b)=0,\ f''(b)\neq0$. We need to get a contradiction.

This question is under the Taylor Expansion chapter although I can't really get anything out of $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(\xi_x)}{2}x^2$ nor by the expansions near $a,b$. I get that in $(-h,h)$ we have $\frac{M}{2}x^2<\frac{|f(0)|}{3}$ which may be related to the 2nd derivative term though.

Comment: Is $f$ twice *continuously* differentiable by any chance?

Comment: No, does it matter?

Comment: Must the root belong to $(-h,h)?$

Comment: Yeah. Otherwise it would be a piece of cake to find a counter-example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $f'(x_0)=0$ with $|x_0|<h.$ Then $|f'(x)|\leq M|x-x_0|< M(|x|+h)$ for all $|x|<h.$ In particular for $0<x<h$ we have $$|f(x)-f(0)|\leq \int_0^h |f'(x)|dx\leq \int_0^h M(x+h)dx<\tfrac32 Mh^2<|f(0)|$$ with the same bound holding for $-h<x<0.$ This means that $f$ cannot have a zero in $(-h,h).$

Comment: How did you come up with this marvelous proof?

Comment: @Theorem: once I saw it could be phrased as bounding $|f(x)-f(0)|$ in terms of $f'$ and $f'',$ then I saw a Taylor's theorem style argument would work. It might seem more obvious if you use Taylor's theorem more literally by first deriving $|f'(0)|\leq Mh$ then using $|f(x)-f(0)|\leq |f'(0)|h+\tfrac12 Mh^2\leq \tfrac32 Mh^2.$

Answer (score -1):

This is not true.
Consider $ f(x) = exp (-x^2) -0.1$

It's not monotone on $(-h,h)$ for any given $h>0$, yet it's second derivative is bounded by a finite $M$ and $f(0)=1$, and it has a root.

Comment: $f (0)=0.9$ .... I think.

Comment: But is the root in $(-h, h)$ with $h=\sqrt{\frac{2|f(0)|}{3M}}$?

Comment: I beg to differ as $M=2$  and the roots aren't in $(-h,h)$ where $h=\sqrt{0.3}$.